# Phabricator API: Assign User to Review Diff

Tags: api, phabricator

Using the phabricator API (authenticated through an API key), how does one programmatically assign a user to review a diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `differential.revision.edit` api call.  Additionally you'll probably need to use `differential.revision.search` and `user.search` or `phid.lookup` to get the PHIDs of the diff and user objects.

```
 echo '{
   "update": "PHID-OF-DIFF-GOES-HERE"
   "type": "reviewers.add", 
   "value": ["PHID-OF-USER-GOES-HERE"]
 }' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri $PHABRICATOR_SERVER_URL --conduit-token $API_TOKEN differential.revision.edit
```